# How to use form POST Method in .htaccess to pass values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are using `.htaccess` to rewrite URLs. For example we use the following method:

```
rewriterule ^profile/([^?/]+)/?$ file.php?name=$1 [NC]
```

and on `file.php` we use the following GET method to receive value from name query string

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
```

Now the issue is I do not want to use this GET method. I do not want to use query string method. I want to use form POST method in `.htaccess` file.

I tried the following method:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(POST)$
```

but I do not know how to use this method.

Comment: You can't inject stuff into the request's body using mod_rewrite, and POST parameters are in a request's body.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a GET request into a POST request without rewriting the code *sending* the data? If so, you're  going to have a bad time

Comment: Are you just trying to Deny post requests or only accept post requests?

Comment: Actually what happend with us. We use to display user details by username or full name and use this method rewriterule ^profile/([^?/]+)/?$ file.php?name=gaurav [NC] then it create url like this sitename.com/gaurav/ but google adsense say that we can not pass any user information in query string coz the adsense use url to display adsense ads and if any personal information passes in url then it will pass in adsense too and this is adsense violation. then what to do now becasue rewrite use query string and we need to display users by name or email too